# When grouping is used in Crystal Reports, lines are displayed strangely

Tags: crystal-reports

I want to use a file used in Crystal Reports 10.x version in 13.x version.
Unfortunately, I don't know the source of the program used by 10.x.
However, since I have the Crystal Reports file, I thought there would be no problem.

This template file uses grouping.
[image]

There is no problem when there is only one group.
[image]

But, When there are more than two group, problems arise.

Example 1.

[image]

Example 2.

[image]

As in the attached picture, if there are more than two groups, the lines are output strangely from the second group.
After the first group, a very small blank line is created. I think this line, the last horizontal line is drawn in a strange position.
Also, there are no vertical lines in the second group.

What is surprising is that this problem does not occur when creating a report using the 10.x version of program

Could you tell me the cause of this?.

When created in 10.x version using the same rpt file.
[image]